¿Es esto una instanciación de una interfaz en java?
Estoy aprendiendo a programar en Java. Según tengo entendido las interfaces en java no se pueden instanciar.
Pero en el código que muestro a continuación creo que hay una instanciación de la interfaz HttpServletRequest y otra de la interfaz HttpServletResponse. Si alguien pudiera aclararme si se puede o no instanciar una interfaz en lenguaje java o qué es lo que se está haciendo aquí.
Muchas gracias de antemano.
Aquí va el código (es de un Servlet que he creado):
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        
        List<Alumno> listaAlumnos = new ArrayList<>();
        listaAlumnos.add(new Alumno("Luis", "luistitosmolina@hotmail.com"));
        listaAlumnos.add(new Alumno("Carla", "carla@hotmail.com"));
        listaAlumnos.add(new Alumno("Julia", "julita@hotmail.com"));
        
        HttpSession miSesion = request.getSession();
        miSesion.setAttribute("listaAlumnos", listaAlumnos);  
    }


Son declaraciones del tipo de parámetros esperados. Cuando una clase implementa una interfaz, dice class XXX implements Interfaz1, Interfaz2, ... { ... }

Hola Luis, bienvenido, siendo A una clase que implementa la interfaz X, puedes hacer lo siguiente, X patitoFeo = new A();, que si bien es un objeto tipo A responde correctamente al contrato estipulado por la interfaz X.

Hola Candid Moe. Sí, eso lo sabía. Lo que no sabía que es que en un parámetro de una función se podía hacer eso de ahí arriba ( Interfaz nombreObjeto ). Gracias por la respuesta.

Hola Marce Puente. Gracias por responder. Sí, eso que me dices tengo entendido que es así. Lo que no sabía es que era posible poner como parámetro de una función MiInterfaz objeto. Mi duda ahora es: esos objetos request y response, del ejemplo que puse arriba, ¿a qué clases pertenecen? Obviamente, tienen que ser clases que implementan aquellas interfaces, HttpServletRequest y HttpServletResponse respectivamente. Pero, ¿cuáles son esas clases? porque no aparecen en el código que yo tengo, bueno, en el código que se crea cuando genero un archivo tipo Servlet en Netbeans.

Luis, perdona la demora, cuando quieras comunicarle algo a otro usuario, usa @nombreUsuario, de esa forma se le notifica que hay un mensaje... vomo te indica Jael en su respuesta, podes usar objeto.getClass().getName(); u objeto.getClass().getSimpleName();.

Gracias @MarcePuente. Como se ve soy nuevo en stackoverflow en lo de programar también.

creo que Marce Puente lo respondio bastante bien, esto se hace para disminuir el acoplamiento de codigo y que no dependa de una implementacion especifica de una clase y que este pueda ser modificado a futuro. Si, si se puede usar como parametros e incluso en un constructor siempre y cuando esa clase tenga un atributo que implementa dicha interfaz. Espero que mi respuesta sea util, ya que aun sigo aprendiendo tambien y dicho esto si hay algo en lo que me he equivocado le agradeceria que me haga la aclaracion :)...
Ahora sobre lo que mencionas de no saber que clase es la que implementa la interfaz, tu servidor es quien se encarga de dar la implementacion concreta y puedes obtenerla con reflection por ejemplo System.out.println(request.getClass().getName());
esto te devuelve el nombre completo, te podria servir este articulo sobre reflection
https://www.arquitecturajava.com/el-concepto-java-reflection/

Jael, maestro, no lo podría describir mejor!!!, solo una nota, getClass() no está relacionado con Reflección es un método heredado de Object.

¡Muchísimas gracias @JaelAlonsoBohorquez!
